# Run Oracle Procedure from .Net controller

Tags: sql, .net, oracle, stored-procedures

I have created an Oracle procedure, and below is the corresponding code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE string_arr AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE web_narudzbenica_test(
    par_id             IN NUMBER,
    par_datum          IN DATE,
    par_kupac_ime      IN VARCHAR2,
    par_kupac_prezime  IN VARCHAR2,
    par_kupac_adresa   IN VARCHAR2,
    par_kupac_ptt_broj IN VARCHAR2,
    par_kupac_mesto    IN VARCHAR2,
    par_kupac_telefon  IN VARCHAR2,
    par_kupac_mail     IN VARCHAR2,
    par_sifra          IN string_arr,
    status OUT NUMBER,
    par_shop_id IN NUMBER := 1
) AS
BEGIN
    -- Your procedure logic here
    -- Access the array elements using the provided associative arrays

    -- Set status to indicate success
    status := 1;
END web_narudzbenica_test;
/
```

I can call this procedure from the DBeaver application without encountering any errors. Below is an example of how I invoke the procedure with sample data:

```
CALL OT.WEB_NARUDZBENICA_TEST(
    123,
    TO_DATE('10-10-2020', 'DD-MM-YYYY'),
    'Test1',
    'Test1',
    'Test1',
    'Test1',
    'Test1',
    '123 123 123',
    'email@email.com',
    string_arr('test1', 'test2', 'test3'),
    ?, 
    1
);
```

Below is my C# controller code:
`` ` ``

```
public async Task<int> CreateNewOrderAsync(OrderDto dto)
    {
        try
        {
            using var command = new OracleCommand
            {
                Connection = _oracleConnection,
                CommandText = "web_narudzbenica_test",
                CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            };

            // Add input parameters
            command.Parameters.Add("par_id", OracleDbType.Int64).Value = 123;
            command.Parameters.Add("par_datum", OracleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.ParseExact("10-10-2020", "dd-MM-yyyy", null);
            command.Parameters.Add("par_kupac_ime", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = "Test1";
            command.Parameters.Add("par_kupac_prezime", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = "Test1";
            command.Parameters.Add("par_kupac_adresa", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = "Test1";
            command.Parameters.Add("par_kupac_ptt_broj", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = "Test1";
            command.Parameters.Add("par_kupac_mesto", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = "Test1";
            command.Parameters.Add("par_kupac_telefon", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = "email@email.com";
            command.Parameters.Add("par_kupac_mail", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = dto.Email;

            OracleParameter Param1 = command.Parameters.Add("par_sifra", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
            Param1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            Param1.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
            Param1.Value = new string[3] {
              "test1", "test2", "test3"
            };
            Param1.Size = 3;
            Param1.ArrayBindSize = new int[3] { 5, 5, 5 };
            Param1.ArrayBindStatus = new OracleParameterStatus[3] {
              OracleParameterStatus.Success, OracleParameterStatus.Success, OracleParameterStatus.Success
            };

            // Add output parameter
            command.Parameters.Add("status", OracleDbType.Int32).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            command.Parameters.Add("par_shop_id", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = dto.ShopId;

            await _oracleConnection.OpenAsync();

            await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

            // Modify the conversion of OracleDecimal to Int32
            OracleDecimal oracleDecimalStatus = (OracleDecimal)command.Parameters["status"].Value;
            int status = oracleDecimalStatus.ToInt32();

            return status;
        }
        finally
        {
            _oracleConnection.Close();
        }

    }
```

The error message I receive is:

```
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'WEB_NARUDZBENICA_TEST'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

...

I suspect the issue arises when attempting to parse the array **`par_sifra`**. I've successfully created a similar procedure without an array, and it works fine. However, when incorporating an array into the parameters, I encounter this problem.

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!